# Changing only the polygons color in metafor R pacakge

Tags: r, plot, r-forestplot

I am trying to do a forest plot of the `Data` (below), but I want to change only the color of the polygon of the combined study.

Code:

```
forest(x = data$beta,sei = data$se,
       xlab = " ",
       psize = c(1,2,3,2,4,6),
       pch = c(15,15,15,15,15,18))
```

Then I thought using:

```
addpoly(x = data$beta,sei = data$se,
        col = c(rep("black",5),"red"),
        pch = c(15,15,15,15,15,18))
```

But this didn't work. The colors are still black.

Data:

```
group   beta    se
Study111    -0.043430833437 0.255182175384
Study112    0.808777362855  0.278587375378
Study113    0.233386044408  0.316660371211
Study114    0.237572509459  0.195872577686
Study115    0.541210360393  0.264106181227
Combined    0.741210360393  0.164106181227
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the color in the `forest` call:

```
forest(x = data$beta,sei = data$se,
   xlab = " ",
   psize = c(1,2,3,2,4,6),
   pch = c(15,15,15,15,15,18),
   col = c(rep('black', 5), 'red'))
```

Comment: That changes the color of the labels and the polygons, I only want the polygons color to change